# Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(\theta x)}{n!},0<\theta <1$ if $f^{'}(0)=...=f^{(n-1)}(0)=0$ using Cauchy's mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't know how to apply theorem on the problem.
By this theorem, if two functions $f$ and $g$ are defined on $[a,b]$ continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g^{'}(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in (a,b)$, then there exists point $c\in (a,b)$ so that
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f{'}(c)}{g^{'}(c)}$$

Can we define $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=n!$? Can we define $\theta$ as a point $c$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^n-0^n},
\end{eqnarray}
by the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, there is $c_1$ such that $c_1$ is between $0$ and $x$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^n-0^n}=\frac{f'(c_1)}{nc_1^{n-1}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Again
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f'(c_1)}{nc_1^{n-1}}=\frac{f'(c_1)-f'(0)}{nc_1^{n-1}-n0^{n-1}},
\end{eqnarray}
and by the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, there is $c_2$ such that $c_2$ between 0 and $c_1$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f'(c_1)}{nc_1^{n-1}}=\frac{f'(c_1)-f'(0)}{nc_1^{n-1}-n0^{n-1}}=\frac{f''(c_2)}{n(n-1)c_2^{n-2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Repeat this $(n-1)$ times and you will get the answer.